# Emacs could not create connection to raw.github.com (gzip not found)

Tags: python, emacs, gzip, x86-64, gnu

I have been trying to code python with Emacs, however after revising my .emacs the program (in which I used `el-get`) wouldn't start up by suggesting "`could not create connection to raw.github.com`", when I run `C:\emacs\bin>runemacs.exe --debug-init` it shows "`uncompression program gzip not found`"

Versions I am using: **Emacs 26.0 (installed with mingw64) + Windows 10 64bit + Python 3.5**.
And my .emacs file is exactly same as here: https://github.com/jhamrick/emacs

Some trials I did but so far not working:

1. Download gzip (but it is a x84 version) copy it to /emacs/bin
2. gzip is originally installed in C:/Program Files (x86)/Gnuwin32 so I also added this into system PATH

As Spyder does not work with Python 3.0+, I decided to switch to Emacs as this is the only other IDE I worked before. In terms of Python with Emacs/lisp I am really new. Hope anyone could give some advice! Thanks!

Comment: Does `C-h v exec-path` include `C:/Program Files (x86)/Gnuwin32` ? Also, is there any particular reason you've decided to install an unstable version of Emacs? If you're having problems that you're not sure how to address, running the latest stable release would seem far more sensible.

Comment: It shows: exec-path is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is
("'$SHELL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\noperable program or batch file.\n")
Original value was 
("'C:/emacs/libexec/emacs/26.0.50/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\noperable program or batch file.\n" "c:/emacs/libexec/emacs/26.0.50/x86_64-w64-mingw32")

Comment: I followed installation here: https://sourceforge.net/p/emacsbinw64/wiki/Build%20guideline%20for%20MSYS2-MinGW-w64%20system/    wasn't aware it is not stable.. just wanted to find one version compatible with win10 x86-64..

Answer (score 1):

> exec-path is a variable defined in ‘C source code’. Its value is ("'$SHELL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\noperable program or batch file.\n") Original value was ("'C:/emacs/libexec/emacs/26.0.50/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdprox‌​y.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\noperable program or batch file.\n" "c:/emacs/libexec/emacs/26.0.50/x86_64-w64-mingw32")

Ok, so that is utterly utterly broken, and explains your problem.

`exec-path` is *supposed* to be a list of directories in which Emacs looks for executables.

I looked at your config, and in `~/.emacs.d/settings/general-settings.el` it's doing this:

```el
; set PATH, because we don't load .bashrc
; function from https://gist.github.com/jakemcc/3887459
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  (setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))
  (let ((path-from-shell (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -i -c 'echo -n $PATH'")))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))

(if window-system (set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH))
```

Clearly that's not working at all.

At minimum you should comment out those lines, but this may also be indicative that this isn't a good config to be using.

If you run into more problems, you may want to look for something more compatible with your system.

---

Regarding the installation instructions, they have you compiling from source, but not selecting a branch, which means you get the bleeding-edge version.

I suggest that within the cloned repository you run:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout emacs-25
```

Emacs 25.2 is at a release-candidate stage, so this branch is a safer recommendation than the one you're currently using.

You'll need to recompile after that. You can reset the repository to a pristine state with:

```
git clean -f -d -x -q
```

and then follow your "configure; make; make install" instructions again.